# Export/Import on different versions of Oracle

Tags: oracle, export

I was wondering, where can i find a step-by-step guide on how to export from a higher version (11g) to a lower version (9i and 10g) of oracle database? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I believe export from 11g to 9i is not supported but will probably work.  11g to 10g is fine.  Basic rules are:

- Export data using the export utility supplied with the lowest of the two databases.
- Import data using the import utility supplied with the target database.

Ideally you want to be using the latest patch release of each version.

You can find the full documentation including step-by-step operation of the export and import utilities here:

- http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/exp_imp.htm